# What's the issue with this sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I couldn't understand the error since everything is correct. OCN is the name of the database. I checked this query on MySQL console it run finely there. But in function code it's giving error. Can anyone help me out to remove the error? Thanks in advance.

This is my sql query :

```
DELETE 
      OCN.practice_sheet_set, 
      OCN.practice_sheet_questions 
FROM 
      OCN.practice_sheet_set AS practice_sheet_set, 
      OCN.practice_sheet_questions AS practice_sheet_questions  
WHERE    
      practice_sheet_set.practice_sheet_set_id = practice_sheet_questions.practice_sheet_set_id 
      AND practice_sheet_set.practice_sheet_id=2
```

MySQL Error :

> 1109 (Unknown table 'practice_sheet_set' in MULTI DELETE)

Comment: Try `DELETE OCN.practice_sheet_set.*, OCN.practice_sheet_questions.*`.

Comment: @Pranay Rana, CornéM: where do you see such syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html ??

Comment: Can you try following

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it should be

```
DELETE 
      practice_sheet_set, 
      practice_sheet_questions 
FROM 
      OCN.practice_sheet_set AS practice_sheet_set, 
      OCN.practice_sheet_questions AS practice_sheet_questions
```

as with the `AS` statements (what's their point in this query?) the `OCN` gets lost.

Answer (score 1):

This query should work

```
DELETE 
      pss, 
      psq 
FROM 
      OCN.practice_sheet_set AS pss, 
      OCN.practice_sheet_questions AS psq  
WHERE    
      pss.practice_sheet_set_id = psq.practice_sheet_set_id 
      AND pss.practice_sheet_id=2
```

Just remove 'AS' or if you are planning to use it, then delete should use table reference instead of table name

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DELETE
    OCN.practice_sheet_set,OCN.practice_sheet_questions
FROM OCN.practice_sheet_set AS practice_sheet_set
where practice_sheet_set.practice_sheet_set_id in
     (select practice_sheet_questions.practice_sheet_set_id
      from OCN.practice_sheet_questions AS practice_sheet_questions
      where practice_sheet_set.practice_sheet_set_id=practice_sheet_questions.practice_sheet_set_id
       AND practice_sheet_set.practice_sheet_id=2);
```